# Erro ao abrir o git hub

Tags: git, github

Olá, ao iniciar o github, ele me mostra uma tela com esse erro:

> error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method) error:
>   unable to unpack 54012a5c5cbe332cb2e1f18539085b14bc0d8542 header
>   fatal: loose object 54012a5c5cbe332cb2e1f18539085b14bc0d8542 (stored
>   in .git/objects/54/012a5c5cbe332cb2e1f18539085b14bc0d8542) is corrupt

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Que se repete mais umas 15 vezes com outros `headers`. 
Outro ponto é que isso só acontece com um `repository`, os demais parecem estar ok.

O problema ocorreu depois de uma queda nos servidores de onde trabalho.

Comment: Parece que os objetos do repositório se corromperam...

Comment: Se eu der um clone novamente resolve? Por que isso ocorreu?

Comment: Responda as perguntas na ordem: 1. Que programa está usando? 2. GithubDesktop? 3. Qual versão do programa? 4. Sua rede usa proxy?

Comment: 1. Que programa está usando? 
R: Como IDE uso o eclipse
2. GithubDesktop?
R: sim
3. Qual versão do programa?
R: 1.0.2
4. Sua rede usa proxy?
R: Sim

Comment: Eu não descobri a real causa do problema, mas, como não ocorreram mais instabilidades de infra, e o problema não ocorreu novamente, eu imagino que essa foi a causa. **A solução foi simplesmente refazer o repositório**.